# Print the ASCII value of the enter key

Tags: python, ascii, linefeed

How should I print the ASCII value of the "enter" key in Python? I have tried `ord()` but it doesn't seem to work for the "enter" keyword. It works for other keywords and characters.

Comment: `ord('\n')` or `ord('\r')`

Comment: how does it not work, what did you try?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `\n` (Line Feed) or `\r`: (Carriage Return).

```
>>> ord('\n')
10
>>> ord('\r')
13
```

as you can see, they are 10 and 13 respectively.

11 is Vertical Tab and 12 is Form Feed.

Answer (score -1):

There is no any single ASCII value for string `enter`. But you can retrieve discrete codes which build up the string.

```
>>> for chr in 'enter':
...     print(ord(chr))
... 
101
110
116
101
114
```

But still what do you mean by `enter keyword` and which `other keywords`?

P.s: It was newline character? Ignore the response then.

Comment: Presumably he wants the enter character? As in Line Break?